# Broadcasting LAN wirelessly?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

Suppose I have a switch that serves as a hub for me to connect to some local network. If I connect my laptop to the switch via ethernet cable using proper settings, I gain access to that network.
Is there a way I can connect some device to the switch using ethernet cable, so that it broadcasts that local network over WiFi? The goal is to wirelessly connect to some device, through which I gain access to the local network, as if I was directly connected to the switch using ethernet cable. Recommendations for specific devices, and/or guidance on how to use some standard network device to achieve said goal would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can connect some device to the switch using ethernet cable, so that it broadcasts that local network over WiFi?

Yes, and that is literally what Wi-Fi does most of the time.

The device providing "pure" Wi-Fi access would usually be called an "**access point**" or **AP**. Although you're used to seeing it in combination with its own IP router, a Wi-Fi AP by itself is just a bridge – in the exact same way that an Ethernet switch is – and will provide access to an existing subnet.

- All consumer "wireless routers" have a Wi-Fi access point built in (that's the "wireless" part of the name – *not* the "router" part!) and some have a dedicated **"AP mode" or "bridge mode"** that configures the device to bypass all IP-level routing and turns it into a plain Wi-Fi AP + Ethernet switch.

  But even in those which do not have a dedicated "AP mode", all necessary parts are already in place, i.e. the built-in AP is active regardless and always bridged to the "LAN" Ethernet ports, so it is usually enough to connect your LAN to such a router's **"LAN" port** and – importantly – **disable DHCP service** and UPnP on such a router. As long as devices don't *try* to use it as a gateway, the "router" will happily act as a basic bridge between Wi-Fi and Ethernet.

  (This is often done to extend coverage of an existing network, and even on this site there's probably a hundred of tutorials for proper configuration of a "wireless router" to turn it into a bridge.)
- Stand-alone "access points" also exist, though they are usually more oriented towards enterprise environments (and enterprise prices, from what I've seen). Every larger Wi-Fi network is built out of many stand-alone APs, all of which are configured to advertise the same SSID and will give access to the same IP subnet (or subnets; they often support multiple VLANs).

  (There *are* cheap stand-alone APs, e.g. "UniFi" seems to be a pretty common brand on the lower end of enterprise; Mikrotik is my usual go-to for highly flexible router/AP devices; others seem to get second-hand enterprise APs from eBay. Often they're physically designed to be ceiling-mounted unlike typical home routers.)
- Finally, PCs with Wi-Fi interfaces can usually act as Wi-Fi access points (though generally not as good quality, and not with all interfaces, and not on all operating systems). If you have a spare Linux device with Wi-Fi – including many, though not all, USB interfaces – most likely it can be configured as an AP/bridge.

  (Again, most tutorials for doing so will include setting up routing, NAT, and everything, but none of that is mandatory – you just need `hostapd` and a bridge interface, ignore the rest.)